# lsusb output has me scratching my head

Tags: lsusb

I don't know if this is normal or not but I have an android device connected via USB

In the charge-only mode the output of the lsusb command shows the vendor/product id as

```
0bb4:0ca3
```

But when I enable usb tethering on the android device, the output of lsusb now shows the product id has changed to

```
0bb4:0ffe
```

Is this normal for the id of a device to change?  Maybe the connection settings for the android display a different id for each setting?

Comment: I cant say for 100% but I would think this was normal, maybe the chip responsible for the tethering reports a different device because the function is so drasticly different, do you get another ID if you connect usb storage, or if you have it, mount USB storage using custom recovery (eg CWM) and see what that reports. ?

Comment: @markkirby I think you are correct. Just confirmed with my own device. That's probably because when you are tethering you device is connected in "modem" mode. The computer sees it like that, unlike in "mass storage" or any other mode.

Comment: I agree with your statement, nothing for the OP to worry about anyway

Comment: I think this is an interesting question mabey someone with more knowledge  of this could explain a bit more about why this happens.

Comment: Thanks for your input...and I agree with marks comment.  My device I mentioned above is an HTC desire...I disconnected it, and connected another device, HTC Kingdom (one), tried the same test...noted the ID when connected charge-only was unique, but when connected in modem-mode, the ID changed to match the other phones modem-mode ID exactly!  Any explanation on this? I've come up with zilch on google...thanks in advance for tackling my curiosity-motivated question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product id is same because the modem chip used in both your (HTC) devices is the same.

I have 3 different USB dongle's, two of which have the same chip Huawei EC1260 and the third has Huawei E398. Please see my lsusb output in attached image.

Can't attach all three USB dongles at the same time, but you can see all three have different device IDs - 16, 19 and 21.

[image: lsusb output showing same and different vendor/product IDs]